# Create prioritization log in Excel - Two lists

Tags: list, excel, vba

I am trying to create a prioritization list.  I have 6 distinct values that the user inputs into a worksheet (by way of a VBA GUI).  Excel calculates these values and creates a prioritization number.  I need to list them (through a function(s)) in two tables.  The problem comes into play when there are duplicate values (ie ProjA = 23 and ProjB = 23).

I don't care which one is listed first, but everything I have tried has secondary issues.  There are two sheets to my work book.  The first is where the "raw" data is entered and the second is where I would like the two lists to be located.  *I do not want to use pivots for these lists.

```
Priority Number Proj Name
57  Project Alpha c
57  DUI Button Project
56  asdf
57  asdfsdfg
56  asdfasdf
56  Project Alpha a
56  Project Alpha b
18  Project BAS
```

List A (would include a value range of 1-20  and
List B (would include a value range of 20 - inf)

```
So, I want it to look like this:

Table 1 (High Priority)                           Table 2 (Low Priority)
Project BAS                                       Project Apha C
                                                  DUI Button Project
                                                  Etc.
```

Comment: What are some of the things you've tried, and what were the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally these open-ended questions aren't received on StackOverflow. You should make an attempt to demonstrate what you've tried so far, and exactly where you're becoming confused. Otherwise people are doing your work for you, rather than trying to solve specific errors.

However, because you're new here, I've made an exception.

You can begin solving your issue by looping through the priority list and copy the values into the appropriate lists. For starters, I assumed that priority values begin at cell `A2` and project names begin at cell `B2` (the cells `A1` and `B1` would be the headers). I also assumed we're using a worksheet called `Sheet1`.

Now I need to know the length of the priority/project name list. I can determine this by using an integer called `maxRows`, calculated by `Worksheets.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row`. This gives the number of values in regular table (including the header, `A1`).

I continue by setting the columns for each priority list (high/low). In my example, I set these to columns `3` and `4`. Then I clear these columns to remove any values that already existed there.

Then I create some tracking variables that will help me determine how many items I've already added to each list (`highPriorityCount` and `lowPriorityCount`).

Finally, I loop through the original list and check if the priority value is low (`< 20`) or high (the `else` condition). The project names are placed into the appropriate column, using the tracking variables I created above.

*Note: Anywhere that uses a `2` as an offset is due to the fact that I am accounting for the header cells (row 1).*

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreatePriorityTables()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ' Determine the length of the main table
        Dim maxRows As Integer
        maxRows = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

        ' Set the location of the priority lists
        Dim highPriorityColumn As Integer
        Dim lowPriorityColumn As Integer
        highPriorityColumn = 3
        lowPriorityColumn = 4

        ' Empty the priority lists
        .Columns(highPriorityColumn).Clear
        .Columns(lowPriorityColumn).Clear

        ' Create headers for priority lists
        .Cells(1, highPriorityColumn).Value = "Table 1 (High Priority)"
        .Cells(1, lowPriorityColumn).Value = "Table 2 (Low Priority)"

        ' Create some useful counts to track
        Dim highPriorityCount As Integer
        Dim lowPriorityCount As Integer
        highPriorityCount = 0
        lowPriorityCount = 0

        ' Loop through all values and copy into priority lists
        Dim currentColumn As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 2 To maxRows
            ' Determine column by priority value
            If (.Cells(i, 1) < 20) Then
                .Cells(lowPriorityCount + 2, lowPriorityColumn).Value = .Cells(i, 2)
                lowPriorityCount = lowPriorityCount + 1
            Else
                .Cells(highPriorityCount + 2, highPriorityColumn).Value = .Cells(i, 2)
                highPriorityCount = highPriorityCount + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

This should produce the expected behavior.

Comment: Not sure which would be faster, but you could also just use a filter on column A, and copy the visible rows.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Definitely. It's less flexible to change to accommodate advanced logic in the future, though.

Comment: @grovesNL - Thank you very much for this.  I am new to all of this (I really mean all of this by way of Excel, posting to forums, ect) and I appreciate your help.  Your response was great and what I was looking for.  I wish you could post examples of your work on here!  Next time I have a question I will follow your recommendations.  We are all in this crazy thing together and I appreciate your patients.